# Add object and array for same properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

```
var obj = {x:{y: {a: 1, b:2}}, p: 11}

var arr = [{x: {y: {c: 3}}},{x: {y: {d: 4}}}]
```

it can be done by lodash `merge(obj, ...arr)`
but I don't want to use lodash merge method

```
outputObj = {x:{y: {a: 1, b:2, c: 3, d: 4}}, p: 11}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and check the type of the value and take either an array or object if a parent property is not given.

```js
function merge(target, ...source) {
    source.forEach(s => Object.entries(s).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            merge(target[k] = target[k] || (Array.isArray(v) ? [] : {}), v);
        } else {
            target[k] = v;
        }
    }));
}

var obj = { x: { y: { a: 1, b: 2 } }, p: 11 },
    arr = [{ x: { y: { c: 3 } } }, { x: { y: { d: 4 } } }]

merge(obj, ...arr)

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Great answer as always! - Check out `const merge = (target, obj) =>  Object.keys (obj).reduce ((merged, key) => ({...merged, [key]: [obj[key]].reduce(merge, target[key]) || obj[key]}), target)` for a super unreadable one liner :P

Answer (score 0):

I found you can do this in "one line" using recursive reduction

```js
const 
    merge = (target, obj) =>
        Object.keys (obj).reduce((merged, key) => ({
             ...merged,
             [key]:[obj[key]].reduce(merge, target[key])||obj[key]
        }), target),
    merged = arr.reduce (merge,obj);

console.log (merged);
```

```html
<script>
var obj = {x:{y: {a: 1, b:2}}, p: 11}
var arr = [{x: {y: {c: 3}}},{x: {y: {d: 4}}}]
</script>
```